# Как вынести данные для авторизации в базе данных MySQL в текстовый файл и подключаться к ней на C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Нужно вынести строки с

```
host = "";
user = "";
password = "";
database = "";
```

в отдельный файл, чтобы каждый раз не лезть в код программы, как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для настроек не принято использовать просто отдельный файл.

Когда вы создаете проект, вместе с ним по умолчанию создается файл App.config в которым вы можете хранить различные настройки. Самые часто используемые секции `connectionStrings` для хранения подключений к БД и `appSettings` для прочих настроек приложения. При этом там можно записать сразу строку подключения напрямую и использовать её. [Смотрите в документации примеры](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из кода программы можно к нему обращаться используя специальный класс ConfigurationManager из System.Configuration.

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"];
            var myValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"];
        }
    }
}
```

В скомпилированном виде этот файл будет называться `{ИмяПроекта}.exe.config`, можно открывать и править.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: благодарю, воспользуюсь! С наступающим Вас!)

Comment: @byte_ и Вас с наступающим!)

Comment: @byte_ учтите, что если вы пишете приложения используя `.net core`, а не `framework`, то там принято держать все настройки приложения в json-формате

Comment: @AndreiKhotko принято или все таки можно в `.config` все же?

Comment: @byte_ можно какой угодно файл, хоть бинарный. Просто `.net core` по умолчанию поддерживает `appsettings.json` и заточен под него. Чтобы использовать другой формат файла, нужно больше манипуляций сделать.